# .NET OpenXML SDK 2 RunProperties are Null

Tags: .net, openxml, docx, word-2007, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to read Word 2007 docx document.

The document looks fine inside Word, but when i try to read id using my code, all Run objects have RunProperites set null.

The property that I'm most interested in is RunProperies.FontSize, but unfortunately it is null as well, the only property I can access is InnerText.

My Code looks like this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
    IList<Paragraph> paragraphList = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().ToList<Paragraph>();

    foreach (Paragraph pr in paragraphList)
    {   
        IList<Run> runList = pr.Elements<Run>().ToList<Run>();
        foreach (Run r in runList)
        {
            // Some logic
        }
    }
}
```

I've minimized my document to as simple as possible, and it looks like this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/204110/test.docx

I have similar document which is read fine. Is it possible that there is a bug in OpenXML SDK 2?

Has anyone had similar problems? Any help would appreciated. 
Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**FontSize** is not a required element, and neither is **RunProperties**. For each run, verify that **r.RunProperties** is not null, and then verify that **r.RunProperties.FontSize** is not null before trying to read the values. Something along the lines of:

```
uint fontSize = SOME_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE;
RunProperties propertiesElement = r.RunProperties;
if (propertiesElement != null) {
  FontSize sizeElement = propertiesElement.FontSize;
    if (sizeElement != null) {
      fontSize = sizeElement.Val.Value;
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at the docx file you supplied using the DocReflector tool that comes with the SDK, you can see that the first 3 runs have a font size specified, but the 4th run does not.

Comment: DocReflector is great....gave me ideas, to get to solution...Thank You very much!

Comment: @Daniil Harik I'm running into the same issue. I assume there is a reference back to default style somewhere. Did you find a solution?